# Build REGEX in SQL automatically

Tags: c#, mysql, regex

I'm now facing a trouble in building a SQL regex searching at runtime.

Somewhat its like:

- User inputs searching string ( one ? represents for 1 character [a-z0-9]):

> AA?001

```
Data:
AAA001
AAB001
AA7001
AA70012
AB0001

Result:
AAA001
AAB001
AA7001
```

At first, I was thinking about the way that splitting it by [+?], then the conditions will be something like:

> Startwith('AA') AND Endwith("001") AND LENGTH = 5)

But this way is not gonna work with pattern: A?0?1. So, I would probably have to build a Regex at runtime, but do not have any clue to do that.

Any suggest/idea/recommend would be grateful.

Comment: You mean this `AA.001 ` ? Add anchors if necessary, `^AA.001$`

Comment: ohh right, just have to replace ? to dot. I dont even know about . before. So new to REGEX. thank you @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 1):

```
^AA[A-Z0-9a-z]001$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wX9fR1/8

```
Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time
```

`? does not match a character on its own.It works on character preceded by it.`

Also add `^$` anchors to disallow a partial match.

```
^AA\S001$
```

If you want to match any character except `space`.

Comment: thank you, but the regex depends on what user inputs. Like: ???001 or A???01, ... So the way AvinashRaj mentioned above will work for me :)

Comment: @Kingcesc `.` will allow `AA 001` too.Do you want to allow `space` too.Use `\S` if you want all but no `space`.